# Is there a way to block ports when using my Android device as a hotspot?

Tags: networking, wifi-hotspot, internet

I often use my Android as a hotspot. I would like to block port 25 for all devices using my hotspot.

Is this possible with Android?

Comment: For this testing I just used a WiFi router that was lying around in the office and blocked traffic via port 25. I would still be interested in finding a solution independent of PC / office network, encase I need to replicate testing environment out of the office.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, but the catch is you have to have the root privilege on your Android phone.

With root privilege, you can use `iptables` to block access to ports of your choice. To block access on port 25, issue these commands:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j DROP
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j DROP
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to use Nmap through your computer. Make a hotspot, connect your PC to it, and use Nmap and `ipconfig`. Not sure if that works, but there isn't any other alternative as far as I know.

In theory, there are some firewall apps, but those rarely work as intended, and you are much better at configuring your Android ports through a PC.

Comment: Yeah you are right firewall apps cant block tetherered traffic, not even netstat can list tethererd traffic.